# df.fillna : Gives Error because of replace value for NaN not present in categorical attributes

Tags: python, pandas, nan

```
df.fillna('unknown',inplace=True)
```

I have a dataframe df wherein some attributes are categorical and some are objects. Using the above expression I am trying to fill missing values in any of these columns with 'unknown'. But I get an erro while doing so saying 'unknown' is not present in categories of the categorical data columns.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and loop through each categorical column and add 'unknown' as a category using [`add_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html) method on the `.cat` accessor.

```
for col in df.select_dtypes('category'):
    df[col].cat.add_categories('unknown', inplace=True)

df.fillna('unknown',inplace=True)
```